# Create date field in DynamoDB table

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I want to use a Zap from Zapier for DynamoDB. I want to use a Zapier Trigger when a new record gets created in the DynamoDB as per the following

> Timestamp Field (required)
>   A field that is a Number and contains a UNIX timestamp. We use this to scan >for recent items.

How do I create a UNIX timestamp field in a DynamoDB table?

Answer (score 0):

Use **Number** data type. There is no timestamp data type in DynamoDB.

Comment: That does not work for Zapier. I have contacted Zapier support and they are trying to help me